# Understand why an event is not in the tail $\sigma$algebra

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ i.i.d random variables and consider the random walk $X_1 + \ldots X_n$.

I consider the event $\{ S_n = 0 \text{ i.o}\}$. I've been told at lectures that this event lies in the **exchangeable $\sigma$-algebra**, but **not in the tail $\sigma$-algebra** $\mathcal{T}= \cap_n \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1}...)$, I'd like to convince myself.

---

Since $\{ S_n = 0 i.o\} = \{ \limsup_n S_n =0 \}$, if I permute a finite number of indices , the limit remains the same, and hence it should belong to the exchangeable sigma algebra.

**BUT** it's not a tail event since if, for instance, I could change the value of $X_1$ with a real large number as to make the limsup stricly positive. Then the event is influenced by a changed of a finite number of $X_n$, and hence would not be in $\mathcal{T}$.

Of course, this is just something intuitive, and now I want to formalize the second one

I note that $$S_{n+k} = S_n + X_{n+1} + \ldots X_{n+k}$$

Hence $$\limsup_n S_n = \limsup_k S_n + X_{n+1} + \ldots + X_{n+k}$$ can I conclude now that this event is not $\sigma(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2})$-measuralbe, and hence it's not a terminal event?

Answer (score 2):

$\{S_n=0 \, i.o.\}$ and $\{lim \sup S_n=0\}$ are very different. If $S_n>0   $ for all $n$  and $S_n \to 0$ almost surely then the first set is empty and the second one has probability $1$.

It is not possible to prove that the first event never belongs to tail sigma filed. For example if $X_i=0$ with probability $1$ then the event becomes $\Omega$ which does belong to the tail sigma filed. What you can say is that this event need not be in the tail sigma field.

Comment: Okay, that's clear, thanks. By the way, is it correct how I showed that $\{ \limsup S_n=0\}$ is not in the tail sigma field ?

Comment: Could  you please confirm if I proved that $\{ \limsup_n S_n = 0\} \notin \mathcal{T}$  in the right way?

Comment: You cannot prove that this event **never** belongs to the tail sigma field. You can only prove (by an example) that it **need not** belong to the tail sigma field. So there is a logical flaw in your argument. @andereBen

Comment: I see your point @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks for pointing that out. So if I take $X_1 >0$, and all the other $X_i, i \geq 2$ to be $X_i=0$, then the $$\limsup S_n =1>0$$ and in order to compute it I can't drop the first $X_i$'s. So it's not a tail event. Could it be okay as an example?

Comment: But you are only allowed to consider i.i.d. seqeuences $(X_i)$. @andereBen

Comment: You're right, and my sequence of $(X_i)'s$ is actually not i.i.d.
So what argument should I use? I'm stuck now @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Could you please give at least a hint?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I'm still trying to find a good example. If I could take $X_i's$ not i.i.d, then my example in the comments should be okay, right?